# how to write query only for selected checkboxes in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

hi i've a requirement that based on user selected checkboxes i've to write a query in hibernate and getback only those selected check box fields back and display to user.for example i've 10 checkboxes in UI page from that if user selects any 5 or 7 or 4 checkbox fields i've to send request to the controller and get back only those selected check box fields for this how can write hibernate query...anyone can suggest me. thanks in advance

Comment: That depends on our table structure and your hibernate mapping. One approach would be to build dynamic HQL(or even SQL) query, another one is to return all values and let the controller filter the displayd values. What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hql **where in** as follows

Assuming you get selected checkboxes as List of Integers

```
List<Integer> checkedList = .....;

String hql = "from Entity where property in (:properties)";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameterList("properties", checkedList);

//get the result as and use it as per use case
List entityList = query.list();
```

You can also evaluate criteria API

```
Restrictions.in(conditionColumnName, conditionColumnValues)
//conditionColumnValues is a collection
```

Hope this helps !!!!!